# Extracting specific values to sheets of the same name Python

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to make a python code that extracts data from one excel sheet and amends it to another excel sheet where the cell value is the same as the sheet name. Here is what I have so far:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
workbook = Workbook()

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('workbook 1.xlsx', 
data_only = True)
ws = wb['Project ']
first_column= ws['B']
second_column = ws['H']
third_column = ws['I']
for x in range(len(first_column)):
    if first_column[x].value != 'ABSENT':
        for x in range(len(second_column)):
            if second_column[x].value != 'No Comment':
                print(first_column[x].value, second_column[x].value, third_column[x].value)
wb0 = openpyxl.load_workbook('workbook 2.xlsx')
ws0 = wb0.sheetnames code here
```

I want python to see if the first column value matches a sheet name in the other workbook, and if it does, extract the first, second, and third column values into that worksheet

Comment: sorry, meant appends it

Answer (score 0):

you can use pandas to load and create excel files:

```
excel_df = pd.read_excel(open(excelpath, 'rb'), header=0)

df.to_excel(excel_df , sheet_name='Your sheet name', index = False)
```

this might help:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html